# Index e valores automáticos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tenho o seguinte Json:

```
{"result":[
          [
           {"ID_CTE":"1","ABREV":"301CAGSP","MODELO":"CT","NUMLANCTO":" 71","NUMCONHEC":" 5911","NUMFATURA":"0000173","NUMREMET":"23.643.315\/0094-51","NUMDESTIN":"23.643.315\/0110-06","NUMREDESP":" ","CODFISCAL":"6.932","DESDOBRAMENTO":"000","DTEMISSAO":"12\/09\/2011","CODCONDPAG":"021","FRETEPORCONTA":"E","FRETEPESOVOL":"1300","VALTOTAL":"1300","VALSEGURO":"0","FRETEVALOR":"0","VALDESPACHO":"0","VALPEDAGIO":"0","VALOUTROS":"0","BASEICMS":"0","ALIQICMS":"0","VALICMS":"0","ALIQREDICMS":"0","VALREDICMS":"0","TIPODESCONTO":"P","PORCEDESCO":"0","VALDESCONTO":"0","IMPRESSA":" ","CANCELADA":"N","RESPICMS":"N","CONHECANT":" ","FRETEPORCONTAR":"E","OBSERV1":"ICMS REC.P\/SUBST. ART 4 ANEXO 15 RICMS\/ MG 02","OBSERV2":" ","OBSERV3":" ","OBSERV4":" ","OBSERV5":" ","OBSERV6":" ","OBSERV7":" ","OBSERV8":" ","OBSERV9":" ","OBSERV10":" ","CODCIDORIGEM":"51800","CODCIDDESTINO":"18800","CODCIDSAIDA":"51800","CODMOTORISTA":"006","CODFROTA":" 005","SERIE":"U","TOMADOR":"R","VALEFSEGURO":"0","VALPREMIOSEG":"0","TIPOFRETE":"04","BASEPIS":"0","ALIQPIS":"0","IMPPIS":"0","ISEPIS":"0","MODALIDADEFRETE":" ","BASECOFINS":"0","ALIQCOFINS":"0","IMPCOFINS":"0","ISECOFINS":"0","CODENDENTR":" ","CAPACIDADE":"0","TARIFACARREGAMENTO":"0","NUMCONSIG":" ","FRETECONSIG":"S","CALCULADOATE":" ","NUMREMETFOR":" ","NUMDESTINFOR":" ","NUMREDESPFOR":" ","NUMCONSIGFOR":" ","CODTRANSPREDESP":" ","ESTCIDSAIDA":"MG","ESTCIDDESTINO":"SP","ESTCIDORIGEM":"MG","CODDIP":" ","CSTPIS":" ","CSTCOFINS":" ","CST":" ","INCIFISC":" ","SITUACAOCT":" ","NUMTOMADOR":" ","NUMTOMADORFOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDORFOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDORFOR":" ","CTECOMPLEM":"N","NUMCTECOMPLEM":" ","SERIECTECOMPLEM":" ","MODCTECOMPLEM":" ","DTSAIDA":" ","VCRED":" ","CODENDDEP":" ","NBMSH":" ","NBS":" ","VALTRIBUTOS":"0","CALCULOMANUALTRIBUTOS":"N"},  
           {"ID_CTE":"2","ABREV":"301CAGSP","MODELO":"CT","NUMLANCTO":" 73","NUMCONHEC":" 5913","NUMFATURA":"0000179","NUMREMET":"57.016.578\/0005-87","NUMDESTIN":"02.060.862\/0002-16","NUMREDESP":" ","CODFISCAL":"5.352","DESDOBRAMENTO":"000","DTEMISSAO":"12\/09\/2011","CODCONDPAG":"021","FRETEPORCONTA":"E","FRETEPESOVOL":"730","VALTOTAL":"1026,69","VALSEGURO":"31,89","FRETEVALOR":"0","VALDESPACHO":"0","VALPEDAGIO":"141,6","VALOUTROS":"0","BASEICMS":"1026,69","ALIQICMS":"12","VALICMS":"123,2","ALIQREDICMS":"0","VALREDICMS":"0","TIPODESCONTO":"P","PORCEDESCO":"0","VALDESCONTO":"0","IMPRESSA":" ","CANCELADA":"N","RESPICMS":"S","CONHECANT":" ","FRETEPORCONTAR":"E","OBSERV1":" ","OBSERV2":" ","OBSERV3":" ","OBSERV4":" ","OBSERV5":" ","OBSERV6":" ","OBSERV7":" ","OBSERV8":" ","OBSERV9":" ","OBSERV10":" ","CODCIDORIGEM":"34401","CODCIDDESTINO":"30706","CODCIDSAIDA":"34401","CODMOTORISTA":"006","CODFROTA":" 005","SERIE":"U","TOMADOR":"R","VALEFSEGURO":"0","VALPREMIOSEG":"0","TIPOFRETE":"03","BASEPIS":"0","ALIQPIS":"0","IMPPIS":"0","ISEPIS":"0","MODALIDADEFRETE":" ","BASECOFINS":"0","ALIQCOFINS":"0","IMPCOFINS":"0","ISECOFINS":"0","CODENDENTR":" ","CAPACIDADE":"123,2","TARIFACARREGAMENTO":"0","NUMCONSIG":" ","FRETECONSIG":"S","CALCULADOATE":" ","NUMREMETFOR":" ","NUMDESTINFOR":" ","NUMREDESPFOR":" ","NUMCONSIGFOR":" ","CODTRANSPREDESP":" ","ESTCIDSAIDA":"SP","ESTCIDDESTINO":"SP","ESTCIDORIGEM":"SP","CODDIP":" ","CSTPIS":" ","CSTCOFINS":" ","CST":" ","INCIFISC":" ","SITUACAOCT":" ","NUMTOMADOR":" ","NUMTOMADORFOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDORFOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDORFOR":" ","CTECOMPLEM":"N","NUMCTECOMPLEM":" ","SERIECTECOMPLEM":" ","MODCTECOMPLEM":" ","DTSAIDA":" ","VCRED":" ","CODENDDEP":" ","NBMSH":" ","NBS":" ","VALTRIBUTOS":"0","CALCULOMANUALTRIBUTOS":"N"},
           {"ID_CTE":"3","ABREV":"301CAGSP","MODELO":"CT","NUMLANCTO":" 76","NUMCONHEC":" 5916","NUMFATURA":"0000189","NUMREMET":"57.016.578\/0005-87","NUMDESTIN":"02.060.862\/0002-16","NUMREDESP":" ","CODFISCAL":"5.352","DESDOBRAMENTO":"000","DTEMISSAO":"13\/09\/2011","CODCONDPAG":"021","FRETEPORCONTA":"E","FRETEPESOVOL":"730","VALTOTAL":"1101,28","VALSEGURO":"97,53","FRETEVALOR":"0","VALDESPACHO":"0","VALPEDAGIO":"141,6","VALOUTROS":"0","BASEICMS":"1101,28","ALIQICMS":"12","VALICMS":"132,15","ALIQREDICMS":"0","VALREDICMS":"0","TIPODESCONTO":"P","PORCEDESCO":"0","VALDESCONTO":"0","IMPRESSA":" ","CANCELADA":"N","RESPICMS":"S","CONHECANT":" ","FRETEPORCONTAR":"E","OBSERV1":" ","OBSERV2":" ","OBSERV3":" ","OBSERV4":" ","OBSERV5":" ","OBSERV6":" ","OBSERV7":" ","OBSERV8":" ","OBSERV9":" ","OBSERV10":" ","CODCIDORIGEM":"34401","CODCIDDESTINO":"30706","CODCIDSAIDA":"34401","CODMOTORISTA":"011","CODFROTA":" 010","SERIE":"U","TOMADOR":"R","VALEFSEGURO":"0","VALPREMIOSEG":"0","TIPOFRETE":"03","BASEPIS":"0","ALIQPIS":"0","IMPPIS":"0","ISEPIS":"0","MODALIDADEFRETE":" ","BASECOFINS":"0","ALIQCOFINS":"0","IMPCOFINS":"0","ISECOFINS":"0","CODENDENTR":" ","CAPACIDADE":"132,15","TARIFACARREGAMENTO":"0","NUMCONSIG":" ","FRETECONSIG":"S","CALCULADOATE":" ","NUMREMETFOR":" ","NUMDESTINFOR":" ","NUMREDESPFOR":" ","NUMCONSIGFOR":" ","CODTRANSPREDESP":" ","ESTCIDSAIDA":"SP","ESTCIDDESTINO":"SP","ESTCIDORIGEM":"SP","CODDIP":" ","CSTPIS":" ","CSTCOFINS":" ","CST":" ","INCIFISC":" ","SITUACAOCT":" ","NUMTOMADOR":" ","NUMTOMADORFOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDORFOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDORFOR":" ","CTECOMPLEM":"N","NUMCTECOMPLEM":" ","SERIECTECOMPLEM":" ","MODCTECOMPLEM":" ","DTSAIDA":" ","VCRED":" ","CODENDDEP":" ","NBMSH":" ","NBS":" ","VALTRIBUTOS":"0","CALCULOMANUALTRIBUTOS":"N"},
           {"ID_CTE":"4","ABREV":"301CAGSP","MODELO":"CT","NUMLANCTO":" 77","NUMCONHEC":" 5917","NUMFATURA":"0000195","NUMREMET":"57.016.578\/0005-87","NUMDESTIN":"02.060.862\/0002-16","NUMREDESP":" ","CODFISCAL":"5.352","DESDOBRAMENTO":"000","DTEMISSAO":"14\/09\/2011","CODCONDPAG":"020","FRETEPORCONTA":"E","FRETEPESOVOL":"730","VALTOTAL":"1027,86","VALSEGURO":"32,92","FRETEVALOR":"0","VALDESPACHO":"0","VALPEDAGIO":"141,6","VALOUTROS":"0","BASEICMS":"1027,86","ALIQICMS":"12","VALICMS":"123,34","ALIQREDICMS":"0","VALREDICMS":"0","TIPODESCONTO":"P","PORCEDESCO":"0","VALDESCONTO":"0","IMPRESSA":" ","CANCELADA":"N","RESPICMS":"S","CONHECANT":" ","FRETEPORCONTAR":"E","OBSERV1":" ","OBSERV2":" ","OBSERV3":" ","OBSERV4":" ","OBSERV5":" ","OBSERV6":" ","OBSERV7":" ","OBSERV8":" ","OBSERV9":" ","OBSERV10":" ","CODCIDORIGEM":"34401","CODCIDDESTINO":"30706","CODCIDSAIDA":"34401","CODMOTORISTA":"001","CODFROTA":" 001","SERIE":"U","TOMADOR":"R","VALEFSEGURO":"0","VALPREMIOSEG":"0","TIPOFRETE":"03","BASEPIS":"0","ALIQPIS":"0","IMPPIS":"0","ISEPIS":"0","MODALIDADEFRETE":" ","BASECOFINS":"0","ALIQCOFINS":"0","IMPCOFINS":"0","ISECOFINS":"0","CODENDENTR":" ","CAPACIDADE":"123,34","TARIFACARREGAMENTO":"0","NUMCONSIG":" ","FRETECONSIG":"S","CALCULADOATE":" ","NUMREMETFOR":" ","NUMDESTINFOR":" ","NUMREDESPFOR":" ","NUMCONSIGFOR":" ","CODTRANSPREDESP":" ","ESTCIDSAIDA":"SP","ESTCIDDESTINO":"SP","ESTCIDORIGEM":"SP","CODDIP":" ","CSTPIS":" ","CSTCOFINS":" ","CST":" ","INCIFISC":" ","SITUACAOCT":" ","NUMTOMADOR":" ","NUMTOMADORFOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDORFOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDORFOR":" ","CTECOMPLEM":"N","NUMCTECOMPLEM":" ","SERIECTECOMPLEM":" ","MODCTECOMPLEM":" ","DTSAIDA":" ","VCRED":" ","CODENDDEP":" ","NBMSH":" ","NBS":" ","VALTRIBUTOS":"0","CALCULOMANUALTRIBUTOS":"N"},
           {"ID_CTE":"5","ABREV":"301CAGSP","MODELO":"CT","NUMLANCTO":" 78","NUMCONHEC":" 5918","NUMFATURA":"0000198","NUMREMET":"43.816.719\/0005-31","NUMDESTIN":"43.816.719\/0009-65","NUMREDESP":" ","CODFISCAL":"6.352","DESDOBRAMENTO":"000","DTEMISSAO":"14\/09\/2011","CODCONDPAG":"031","FRETEPORCONTA":"E","FRETEPESOVOL":"2450","VALTOTAL":"3227,65","VALSEGURO":"146,43","FRETEVALOR":"0","VALDESPACHO":"0","VALPEDAGIO":"243,9","VALOUTROS":"0","BASEICMS":"3227,65","ALIQICMS":"12","VALICMS":"387,32","ALIQREDICMS":"0","VALREDICMS":"0","TIPODESCONTO":"P","PORCEDESCO":"0","VALDESCONTO":"0","IMPRESSA":" ","CANCELADA":"N","RESPICMS":"S","CONHECANT":" ","FRETEPORCONTAR":"E","OBSERV1":" ","OBSERV2":" ","OBSERV3":" ","OBSERV4":" ","OBSERV5":" ","OBSERV6":" ","OBSERV7":" ","OBSERV8":" ","OBSERV9":" ","OBSERV10":" ","CODCIDORIGEM":"50308","CODCIDDESTINO":"04557","CODCIDSAIDA":"50308","CODMOTORISTA":"006","CODFROTA":" 005","SERIE":"U","TOMADOR":"R","VALEFSEGURO":"0","VALPREMIOSEG":"0","TIPOFRETE":"03","BASEPIS":"0","ALIQPIS":"0","IMPPIS":"0","ISEPIS":"0","MODALIDADEFRETE":" ","BASECOFINS":"0","ALIQCOFINS":"0","IMPCOFINS":"0","ISECOFINS":"0","CODENDENTR":" ","CAPACIDADE":"387,32","TARIFACARREGAMENTO":"0","NUMCONSIG":" ","FRETECONSIG":"S","CALCULADOATE":" ","NUMREMETFOR":" ","NUMDESTINFOR":" ","NUMREDESPFOR":" ","NUMCONSIGFOR":" ","CODTRANSPREDESP":" ","ESTCIDSAIDA":"SP","ESTCIDDESTINO":"GO","ESTCIDORIGEM":"SP","CODDIP":" ","CSTPIS":" ","CSTCOFINS":" ","CST":" ","INCIFISC":" ","SITUACAOCT":" ","NUMTOMADOR":" ","NUMTOMADORFOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDORFOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDORFOR":" ","CTECOMPLEM":"N","NUMCTECOMPLEM":" ","SERIECTECOMPLEM":" ","MODCTECOMPLEM":" ","DTSAIDA":" ","VCRED":" ","CODENDDEP":" ","NBMSH":" ","NBS":" ","VALTRIBUTOS":"0","CALCULOMANUALTRIBUTOS":"N"}
          ]
          ]
}
```

Quando eu chamo esse Json no Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'jsonTabelaSistema.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
    success: function(json){
    console.log(json);
    },
    error: function(json){
        alert('erro');
    }
});
```

Precisava que imprimisse o campo e o valor dinamicamente, por ex:

> ID_CTE 
>  1 
>  ABREV 
>  301CAGSP

Para pegar automaticamente, eu fiz isso em PHP, dessa maneira com o `file_get_contents` e `json_decode()` :

```
foreach($obj as $chave => $array) {
    foreach($array as $index => $pessoa) {
        foreach($pessoa as $dado => $valor) {
            $valorArray = get_object_vars($valor);
            foreach ($valorArray as $key => $value) {
                $campo = $key;  
                $valor = $valor->$key; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fala guri beleza?

Você pode dar um loop nos itens de um objeto

Exemplo abaixo:

```
var teste = {"result":[
          [
           {"ID_CTE":"1","ABREV":"301CAGSP","MODELO":"CT","NUMLANCTO":" 71","NUMCONHEC":" 5911","NUMFATURA":"0000173","NUMREMET":"23.643.315\/0094-51","NUMDESTIN":"23.643.315\/0110-06","NUMREDESP":" ","CODFISCAL":"6.932","DESDOBRAMENTO":"000","DTEMISSAO":"12\/09\/2011","CODCONDPAG":"021","FRETEPORCONTA":"E","FRETEPESOVOL":"1300","VALTOTAL":"1300","VALSEGURO":"0","FRETEVALOR":"0","VALDESPACHO":"0","VALPEDAGIO":"0","VALOUTROS":"0","BASEICMS":"0","ALIQICMS":"0","VALICMS":"0","ALIQREDICMS":"0","VALREDICMS":"0","TIPODESCONTO":"P","PORCEDESCO":"0","VALDESCONTO":"0","IMPRESSA":" ","CANCELADA":"N","RESPICMS":"N","CONHECANT":" ","FRETEPORCONTAR":"E","OBSERV1":"ICMS REC.P\/SUBST. ART 4 ANEXO 15 RICMS\/ MG 02","OBSERV2":" ","OBSERV3":" ","OBSERV4":" ","OBSERV5":" ","OBSERV6":" ","OBSERV7":" ","OBSERV8":" ","OBSERV9":" ","OBSERV10":" ","CODCIDORIGEM":"51800","CODCIDDESTINO":"18800","CODCIDSAIDA":"51800","CODMOTORISTA":"006","CODFROTA":" 005","SERIE":"U","TOMADOR":"R","VALEFSEGURO":"0","VALPREMIOSEG":"0","TIPOFRETE":"04","BASEPIS":"0","ALIQPIS":"0","IMPPIS":"0","ISEPIS":"0","MODALIDADEFRETE":" ","BASECOFINS":"0","ALIQCOFINS":"0","IMPCOFINS":"0","ISECOFINS":"0","CODENDENTR":" ","CAPACIDADE":"0","TARIFACARREGAMENTO":"0","NUMCONSIG":" ","FRETECONSIG":"S","CALCULADOATE":" ","NUMREMETFOR":" ","NUMDESTINFOR":" ","NUMREDESPFOR":" ","NUMCONSIGFOR":" ","CODTRANSPREDESP":" ","ESTCIDSAIDA":"MG","ESTCIDDESTINO":"SP","ESTCIDORIGEM":"MG","CODDIP":" ","CSTPIS":" ","CSTCOFINS":" ","CST":" ","INCIFISC":" ","SITUACAOCT":" ","NUMTOMADOR":" ","NUMTOMADORFOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDORFOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDORFOR":" ","CTECOMPLEM":"N","NUMCTECOMPLEM":" ","SERIECTECOMPLEM":" ","MODCTECOMPLEM":" ","DTSAIDA":" ","VCRED":" ","CODENDDEP":" ","NBMSH":" ","NBS":" ","VALTRIBUTOS":"0","CALCULOMANUALTRIBUTOS":"N"},  
           {"ID_CTE":"2","ABREV":"301CAGSP","MODELO":"CT","NUMLANCTO":" 73","NUMCONHEC":" 5913","NUMFATURA":"0000179","NUMREMET":"57.016.578\/0005-87","NUMDESTIN":"02.060.862\/0002-16","NUMREDESP":" ","CODFISCAL":"5.352","DESDOBRAMENTO":"000","DTEMISSAO":"12\/09\/2011","CODCONDPAG":"021","FRETEPORCONTA":"E","FRETEPESOVOL":"730","VALTOTAL":"1026,69","VALSEGURO":"31,89","FRETEVALOR":"0","VALDESPACHO":"0","VALPEDAGIO":"141,6","VALOUTROS":"0","BASEICMS":"1026,69","ALIQICMS":"12","VALICMS":"123,2","ALIQREDICMS":"0","VALREDICMS":"0","TIPODESCONTO":"P","PORCEDESCO":"0","VALDESCONTO":"0","IMPRESSA":" ","CANCELADA":"N","RESPICMS":"S","CONHECANT":" ","FRETEPORCONTAR":"E","OBSERV1":" ","OBSERV2":" ","OBSERV3":" ","OBSERV4":" ","OBSERV5":" ","OBSERV6":" ","OBSERV7":" ","OBSERV8":" ","OBSERV9":" ","OBSERV10":" ","CODCIDORIGEM":"34401","CODCIDDESTINO":"30706","CODCIDSAIDA":"34401","CODMOTORISTA":"006","CODFROTA":" 005","SERIE":"U","TOMADOR":"R","VALEFSEGURO":"0","VALPREMIOSEG":"0","TIPOFRETE":"03","BASEPIS":"0","ALIQPIS":"0","IMPPIS":"0","ISEPIS":"0","MODALIDADEFRETE":" ","BASECOFINS":"0","ALIQCOFINS":"0","IMPCOFINS":"0","ISECOFINS":"0","CODENDENTR":" ","CAPACIDADE":"123,2","TARIFACARREGAMENTO":"0","NUMCONSIG":" ","FRETECONSIG":"S","CALCULADOATE":" ","NUMREMETFOR":" ","NUMDESTINFOR":" ","NUMREDESPFOR":" ","NUMCONSIGFOR":" ","CODTRANSPREDESP":" ","ESTCIDSAIDA":"SP","ESTCIDDESTINO":"SP","ESTCIDORIGEM":"SP","CODDIP":" ","CSTPIS":" ","CSTCOFINS":" ","CST":" ","INCIFISC":" ","SITUACAOCT":" ","NUMTOMADOR":" ","NUMTOMADORFOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDORFOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDORFOR":" ","CTECOMPLEM":"N","NUMCTECOMPLEM":" ","SERIECTECOMPLEM":" ","MODCTECOMPLEM":" ","DTSAIDA":" ","VCRED":" ","CODENDDEP":" ","NBMSH":" ","NBS":" ","VALTRIBUTOS":"0","CALCULOMANUALTRIBUTOS":"N"},
           {"ID_CTE":"3","ABREV":"301CAGSP","MODELO":"CT","NUMLANCTO":" 76","NUMCONHEC":" 5916","NUMFATURA":"0000189","NUMREMET":"57.016.578\/0005-87","NUMDESTIN":"02.060.862\/0002-16","NUMREDESP":" ","CODFISCAL":"5.352","DESDOBRAMENTO":"000","DTEMISSAO":"13\/09\/2011","CODCONDPAG":"021","FRETEPORCONTA":"E","FRETEPESOVOL":"730","VALTOTAL":"1101,28","VALSEGURO":"97,53","FRETEVALOR":"0","VALDESPACHO":"0","VALPEDAGIO":"141,6","VALOUTROS":"0","BASEICMS":"1101,28","ALIQICMS":"12","VALICMS":"132,15","ALIQREDICMS":"0","VALREDICMS":"0","TIPODESCONTO":"P","PORCEDESCO":"0","VALDESCONTO":"0","IMPRESSA":" ","CANCELADA":"N","RESPICMS":"S","CONHECANT":" ","FRETEPORCONTAR":"E","OBSERV1":" ","OBSERV2":" ","OBSERV3":" ","OBSERV4":" ","OBSERV5":" ","OBSERV6":" ","OBSERV7":" ","OBSERV8":" ","OBSERV9":" ","OBSERV10":" ","CODCIDORIGEM":"34401","CODCIDDESTINO":"30706","CODCIDSAIDA":"34401","CODMOTORISTA":"011","CODFROTA":" 010","SERIE":"U","TOMADOR":"R","VALEFSEGURO":"0","VALPREMIOSEG":"0","TIPOFRETE":"03","BASEPIS":"0","ALIQPIS":"0","IMPPIS":"0","ISEPIS":"0","MODALIDADEFRETE":" ","BASECOFINS":"0","ALIQCOFINS":"0","IMPCOFINS":"0","ISECOFINS":"0","CODENDENTR":" ","CAPACIDADE":"132,15","TARIFACARREGAMENTO":"0","NUMCONSIG":" ","FRETECONSIG":"S","CALCULADOATE":" ","NUMREMETFOR":" ","NUMDESTINFOR":" ","NUMREDESPFOR":" ","NUMCONSIGFOR":" ","CODTRANSPREDESP":" ","ESTCIDSAIDA":"SP","ESTCIDDESTINO":"SP","ESTCIDORIGEM":"SP","CODDIP":" ","CSTPIS":" ","CSTCOFINS":" ","CST":" ","INCIFISC":" ","SITUACAOCT":" ","NUMTOMADOR":" ","NUMTOMADORFOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDORFOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDORFOR":" ","CTECOMPLEM":"N","NUMCTECOMPLEM":" ","SERIECTECOMPLEM":" ","MODCTECOMPLEM":" ","DTSAIDA":" ","VCRED":" ","CODENDDEP":" ","NBMSH":" ","NBS":" ","VALTRIBUTOS":"0","CALCULOMANUALTRIBUTOS":"N"},
           {"ID_CTE":"4","ABREV":"301CAGSP","MODELO":"CT","NUMLANCTO":" 77","NUMCONHEC":" 5917","NUMFATURA":"0000195","NUMREMET":"57.016.578\/0005-87","NUMDESTIN":"02.060.862\/0002-16","NUMREDESP":" ","CODFISCAL":"5.352","DESDOBRAMENTO":"000","DTEMISSAO":"14\/09\/2011","CODCONDPAG":"020","FRETEPORCONTA":"E","FRETEPESOVOL":"730","VALTOTAL":"1027,86","VALSEGURO":"32,92","FRETEVALOR":"0","VALDESPACHO":"0","VALPEDAGIO":"141,6","VALOUTROS":"0","BASEICMS":"1027,86","ALIQICMS":"12","VALICMS":"123,34","ALIQREDICMS":"0","VALREDICMS":"0","TIPODESCONTO":"P","PORCEDESCO":"0","VALDESCONTO":"0","IMPRESSA":" ","CANCELADA":"N","RESPICMS":"S","CONHECANT":" ","FRETEPORCONTAR":"E","OBSERV1":" ","OBSERV2":" ","OBSERV3":" ","OBSERV4":" ","OBSERV5":" ","OBSERV6":" ","OBSERV7":" ","OBSERV8":" ","OBSERV9":" ","OBSERV10":" ","CODCIDORIGEM":"34401","CODCIDDESTINO":"30706","CODCIDSAIDA":"34401","CODMOTORISTA":"001","CODFROTA":" 001","SERIE":"U","TOMADOR":"R","VALEFSEGURO":"0","VALPREMIOSEG":"0","TIPOFRETE":"03","BASEPIS":"0","ALIQPIS":"0","IMPPIS":"0","ISEPIS":"0","MODALIDADEFRETE":" ","BASECOFINS":"0","ALIQCOFINS":"0","IMPCOFINS":"0","ISECOFINS":"0","CODENDENTR":" ","CAPACIDADE":"123,34","TARIFACARREGAMENTO":"0","NUMCONSIG":" ","FRETECONSIG":"S","CALCULADOATE":" ","NUMREMETFOR":" ","NUMDESTINFOR":" ","NUMREDESPFOR":" ","NUMCONSIGFOR":" ","CODTRANSPREDESP":" ","ESTCIDSAIDA":"SP","ESTCIDDESTINO":"SP","ESTCIDORIGEM":"SP","CODDIP":" ","CSTPIS":" ","CSTCOFINS":" ","CST":" ","INCIFISC":" ","SITUACAOCT":" ","NUMTOMADOR":" ","NUMTOMADORFOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDORFOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDORFOR":" ","CTECOMPLEM":"N","NUMCTECOMPLEM":" ","SERIECTECOMPLEM":" ","MODCTECOMPLEM":" ","DTSAIDA":" ","VCRED":" ","CODENDDEP":" ","NBMSH":" ","NBS":" ","VALTRIBUTOS":"0","CALCULOMANUALTRIBUTOS":"N"},
           {"ID_CTE":"5","ABREV":"301CAGSP","MODELO":"CT","NUMLANCTO":" 78","NUMCONHEC":" 5918","NUMFATURA":"0000198","NUMREMET":"43.816.719\/0005-31","NUMDESTIN":"43.816.719\/0009-65","NUMREDESP":" ","CODFISCAL":"6.352","DESDOBRAMENTO":"000","DTEMISSAO":"14\/09\/2011","CODCONDPAG":"031","FRETEPORCONTA":"E","FRETEPESOVOL":"2450","VALTOTAL":"3227,65","VALSEGURO":"146,43","FRETEVALOR":"0","VALDESPACHO":"0","VALPEDAGIO":"243,9","VALOUTROS":"0","BASEICMS":"3227,65","ALIQICMS":"12","VALICMS":"387,32","ALIQREDICMS":"0","VALREDICMS":"0","TIPODESCONTO":"P","PORCEDESCO":"0","VALDESCONTO":"0","IMPRESSA":" ","CANCELADA":"N","RESPICMS":"S","CONHECANT":" ","FRETEPORCONTAR":"E","OBSERV1":" ","OBSERV2":" ","OBSERV3":" ","OBSERV4":" ","OBSERV5":" ","OBSERV6":" ","OBSERV7":" ","OBSERV8":" ","OBSERV9":" ","OBSERV10":" ","CODCIDORIGEM":"50308","CODCIDDESTINO":"04557","CODCIDSAIDA":"50308","CODMOTORISTA":"006","CODFROTA":" 005","SERIE":"U","TOMADOR":"R","VALEFSEGURO":"0","VALPREMIOSEG":"0","TIPOFRETE":"03","BASEPIS":"0","ALIQPIS":"0","IMPPIS":"0","ISEPIS":"0","MODALIDADEFRETE":" ","BASECOFINS":"0","ALIQCOFINS":"0","IMPCOFINS":"0","ISECOFINS":"0","CODENDENTR":" ","CAPACIDADE":"387,32","TARIFACARREGAMENTO":"0","NUMCONSIG":" ","FRETECONSIG":"S","CALCULADOATE":" ","NUMREMETFOR":" ","NUMDESTINFOR":" ","NUMREDESPFOR":" ","NUMCONSIGFOR":" ","CODTRANSPREDESP":" ","ESTCIDSAIDA":"SP","ESTCIDDESTINO":"GO","ESTCIDORIGEM":"SP","CODDIP":" ","CSTPIS":" ","CSTCOFINS":" ","CST":" ","INCIFISC":" ","SITUACAOCT":" ","NUMTOMADOR":" ","NUMTOMADORFOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDOR":" ","NUMRECEBEDORFOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDOR":" ","NUMEXPEDIDORFOR":" ","CTECOMPLEM":"N","NUMCTECOMPLEM":" ","SERIECTECOMPLEM":" ","MODCTECOMPLEM":" ","DTSAIDA":" ","VCRED":" ","CODENDDEP":" ","NBMSH":" ","NBS":" ","VALTRIBUTOS":"0","CALCULOMANUALTRIBUTOS":"N"}
          ]
          ]
}

for (var k in teste.result[0][0]) {
    //Imprime a chave
    console.log(k);
    //Imprime o valor
    console.log(teste.result[0][0][k]);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: mas uma vez vc me ajudando mto! agradeço seu tempo! obrigado mesmo!